# How to Add One Day in Python Calendar Module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to coding, please excuse any basic mistakes. I've been working on this piece of code that uses the Python calendar module to generate a start date. Everything was working well until I realised that I also needed an end date. I tried manually adding 1 to the start date, and I realised when I printed the output that this is not going to work once it gets to the end of the month.
This is the incorrect output I get. Obviously, December does not have 32 days in it.
Start date is 2015-12-31.
End date is 2015-12-32.
I've been reading documents on the calendar module, but I haven't seen anything yet (that made sense to me) on how to get this working.
This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json 
import calendar

cal = calendar.Calendar()
for year in range(2015,2016):
    for month in range(1,13):
        monthdays = [d for d in cal.itermonthdays(year,month) if d != 0]
        for day in monthdays:
            str_year = str(year)
            if month < 10:
                str_month = "0" + str(month)
                # print(str_month)
            else:
                str_month = str(month)
                # print(str_month)
            if day < 10:
                str_StartDay = "0" + str(day)
                int_EndDay = day + 1
                if int_EndDay < 10:
                    str_EndDay = "0" + str(int_EndDay)
                else:
                    str_EndDay = str(int_EndDay)
            else:
                str_StartDay = str(day)
                int_EndDay = day + 1
                str_EndDay = str(int_EndDay)
                # print(str_day)
            _STARTDATE = str_year + "-" + str_month + "-" + str_StartDay
            _ENDDATE = str_year + "-" + str_month + "-" + str_EndDay
            # print(_DATE)
            #fun_Phase1(_DATE)
            print("Start date is " + _STARTDATE)
            print("End date is " + _ENDDATE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the `datetime` lib for date and time calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Klaus D. You've pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using datetime to solve this problem. Here is the code. Hopefully this saves someone time in the future.

```
import requests
import json 
import calendar
import datetime

cal = calendar.Calendar()
for year in range(2015,2016):
    for month in range(1,13):
        monthdays = [d for d in cal.itermonthdays(year,month) if d != 0]
        for day in monthdays:
            str_year = str(year)
            int_year = int(year)
            if month < 10:
                str_month = "0" + str(month)
                int_month = int(month)
                # print(str_month)
            else:
                str_month = str(month)
                int_month = int(month)
                # print(str_month)
            if day < 10:
                str_StartDay = "0" + str(day)
                int_day = int(day)
            else:
                str_StartDay = str(day)
                int_day = int(day)
                # print(str_day)
            _MYDATE = datetime.date(int_year,int_month,int_day)
            str_MYDATE = str(_MYDATE)
            print(str_MYDATE)
            _MYDATEPLUSONE = _MYDATE + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            str_MYDATEPLUSONE = str(_MYDATEPLUSONE)
            print(str_MYDATEPLUSONE)
            print("Start date is " + str_MYDATE)
            print("End date is " + str_MYDATEPLUSONE)
```